# How to send text fields data from list to another screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

if I have so many text field from list and all of them in list View builder now how to send selected fields data to another screen in flutter

Comment: Have you read [cookbooks](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)?

Answer (score 0):

First Screen,pass data in Navigator:

```
Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>secondscreen('value')),
          );
```

in Second Screen:

```
class secondscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  secondscreen(this.uid);  
  final uid;
  @override
  secondscreenstate createState() => secondscreenstate (this.uid);
}

class secondscreenstate extends State<secondscreen> {
 
  var uid; //where uid will carry the value from first screen
  secondscreenstate (this.uid);
.......

}
```